# Preventing Function App or Logic App Naming Clashes

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

When creating an Azure FA/LA the name is concatenated with ".azurewebsites.net". At the point of creation this must be a unique URL. We occasionally get naming clashes with other Azure users who have created FA/LA for similar business functions (Following the Microsoft naming standards for FA/LA almost guarantee a name clash with other Azure hosted customers).

I can add a new "A record" to generate a URL based on my domain name - but I dont seem to nominate a domain at the point of creation, and therefore avoid the almost-certain name clash. Is there a way of doing this (or other method of avoiding name clashes) ?

Based on feedback from @Skin I also find that prefixing a function app with a company name to make it unique-ish may have problems; Azure truncates the function App name when accessing its storage account.

The Azure naming convention page only provides examples of naming conventions unique within the tenancy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-naming?source=recommendations - I want to be able to override the .azurewebsites.net domain with my own one - to guarantee uniqueness (which is partially what domains are for).

Comment: No, it’s globally unique. Be sure to put your company/business/acronym name in the name of the app. It’s just life.

Comment: @Skin - thanks for the response - its a really weird situation to have to put the company name on the function app, as this is what domain names are designed for. I've adjusted my question to put in some other info I've found regarding function app naming to clarify what I've found (and why maybe prefixing the function app with the company name might not be a good idea - maybe suffixing it, is what you were recommending ?)

Comment: Yes but when it comes to cloud architecture, your private domain is secondary to the Azure service.  Ultimately, the infrastructure and backend services are owned and hosted on Microsoft's hardware, therefore, the domains attached to those services is under the Microsoft domain banner when initially created.  Functions aren't the only one. Storage accounts, service bus namespaces, IoT hubs, Synapse endpoints, etc. need to all be globally unique.  You'll see that functions do have the ability to work against your own domain, but, the instance you create must first be globally unique.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extremely key point that is mentioned in the link you provided ...

> Some resource names, such as PaaS services with public endpoints or virtual machine DNS labels, have global scopes, so they must be unique across the entire Azure platform.

Azure functions falls into that category.

In those instances, you may have the option to add your own domain name.  I personally have done it for an APIM instance which surfaces and ultimately load balances a whole heap of Azure Function endpoints behind the scenes.

For functions, you can see it in the blade itself ...

[image: Functions]